# main.g.cs and app.g.cs bypass for wp7 in VS 2012

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm doing an app for wp7 with Visual Studio 2012, I have already coded all of it, but when I want to debug it, I have problems with the pages main.g.cs and app.g.cs, which are automatically made.

I have my main.xaml linked to the main.xaml.cs, as well as the app.xaml with app.g.cs, but when I try to debug it, they use the "main.g.cs" instead of the "main.xaml.cs", with the following error:

> The type 'X.main' already contains a definition for 'connectionList'   C:\Users...\obj\Debug\controller\main.g.cs$

I put the definition of connectionList on the main.xaml.cs page, but on the main.g.cs I have this definition

```
public partial class main : Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage {
    
    ...       
    internal System.Windows.Controls.ListBox connectionList;
...

 [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri(".../main.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
        this.connectionList = ((System.Windows.Controls.ListBox)    (this.FindName("connectionList")));
```

I have try different methods to fix this (deleted and recreated the main.xaml, set build action)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you already defined a ListBox in the Main.xaml with the name `connectionList` . Try to rename your list with another name like `myConnectionList` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

When I change the name to myConnectionList on the main.xaml and main.xaml.cs, it automatically change the deffinition on the main.g.cs to myConnectionList, and continue to use the main.g.cs instead of the main.xaml.cs